# C Linux Signal Handling

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm new to the OS and I met some problems when learning Linux signal handling.

In Linux, if a signal arrives during a syscall such as pause(), the program will switch to kernel mode and runs the signal handler. Then depending on the handler function, the program will do whatever the function tells it to do. What if the syscall is important and can't/shouldn't be interrupted? (Or does there exist such sys call that can't be interrupted by a signal?)

Also, what would happen if a signal arrives when the kernel is processing another signal which arrived earlier? Will the new signal be captured later?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16455/interruption-of-system-calls-when-a-signal-is-caught

Comment: Your question is rather broad, with multiple questions in it. Signal handlers are a broad subject, so maybe you could edit it to highlight just what is the thing you are asking about, with just one or two actual questions... (Btw, signal handlers do not run in kernel mode.)

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaken. A signal handler does not run in kernel mode, but in user mode. It would be a major escalation of privileges bug is a normal application could get kernel mode access.

You're also wondering about a syscall being interrupted. This isn't a concern, for the same reason: the signal affects only the application, not the kernel handling the syscall.

Comment: Not quite. Signals can interrupt syscalls.

Comment: @n.m.: You mean that a syscall can return early (and fail) when a signal arrives? I don't think syscalls are paused and resumed by the handling of the signal.

Comment: @n.m. : I guess this may be a difference in perspective (kernel/user code). I think you refer to `SA_RESTART` where the C library deals with `EINTR` by re-issuing the call. But see also [glibc](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_24.html#SEC497) explicitly stating that `read` and `write` are not reissued.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a syscall to be interrupted by a signal, you can mask all (catchable) signals with `sigprocmask(2)`:

```
sigset_t fullset;
sigfillset(&fullset);
sigprocmask(SiG_SETMASK, fullset, NULL);
```

`SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` can not be blocked.

If a signal arrived while it was blocked the handler will be executed when the corresponding signal is removed from the mask again.